# Laravel Charts: Passing variable to handler function

Tags: php, laravel, charts

I followed the guide on https://charts.erik.cat/guide/ to install Chartisan with echarts in my Laravel 7.4 framework. Everything works fine and I receive a chart.

The chart is triggered with this handler function:

```
public function handler(Request $request): Chartisan
    {
        return Chartisan::build()
            ->labels(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
            ->dataset('Sample', [1, 2, 3])
            ->dataset('Sample 2', [3, 2, 1]);
    }
```

The dataset shall be pulled from my database therefore I modify the code to:

```
public function handler(Request $request): Chartisan
    {
        $data = DB::Users->where('id',$id)->find(1); //$id is not defined

        return Chartisan::build()
            ->labels(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
            ->dataset('Sample', [1, 2, 3])
            ->dataset('Sample 2', [3, 2, 1]);
    }
```

Of course this doesn't work because $id is not defined. How and where can I pass data to the handler function? How can I use the $request variable if it is not a form?

The chart is called via the api/chart/SampleChart route. Where is this route defined? Could I pass data to the route? It is not included in routes/api.php or web.php.

All Laravel/Chart examples with the handler function are using ALL data from the database table without restrictions. I did not find an example which passes data.

`global $id` does not work to get access to $id.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily pass parameters from your view to your chart url with "?":

http://localhost/public/api/chart/sample_chart?id=1

like this:

```
const chart = new Chartisan({
        el: '#chart',
        url: "@chart('sample_chart')" + "?id=1"
});
```

this part `"?id=1"` I would do something like this `"?id={{ $id_came_from_controller }}"`

and then in your `handle(Request $request)` method you can access your $id like this:

```
$id = $request->id;
$data = DB::Users->where('id', $id)->first();
```

P.S.

if you need several parameters, you can pass like this:

http://localhost/public/api/chart/sample_chart?first_param=123&second_param=456&third_param=789

and retrieve:

```
$request->first_param;
$request->second_param;
$request->third_param;
```

Answer (score 1):

The handler method is used to show static example in the docs.

You can directly instantiate the SampleChart, by adding it into the controller, If you have SampleChart inside App->Charts->SampleChart.php, you can add `use App\Charts\SampleChart`

Add a contructor to your sample chart, not know if they provide in recent versions by default,

```
class SampleChart extends Basechart
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__contruct();
    }
```

Then create instance

```
$samplechart = new SampleChart;
$data = DB::Users->find(1); // either use DB::Users->where('id',$id)->first();
/**
* let $data looks like, $data->name = "bhucho";$data->id = 2;$data->hobby = stoverflow; 
*/

$samplechart->labels = (array_keys($data));
$samplechart->dataset = (array_values($data));

return view('yourview', compact('samplechart'));
```

Also add these to your SampleChart as mentioned in [chart_configuration](https://charts.erik.cat/guide/chart_configuration.html).

```
 public ?string $name = 'custom_chart_name';
 public ?string $routeName = 'chart_route_name';
```

Comment: I am getting an error `Call to undefined method ConsoleTVs\Charts\BaseChart::__contruct()`

Comment: It works for version < 5.4, the code changes drastically in version 5, 6 & 7,

Comment: use this doc for version 6, https://v6.charts.erik.cat/adding_datasets.html#database-eloquent-example , honestly this doc of version 7 https://chartisan.dev/documentation has very less info, version 6 should solve your problem, I would update the answer but quite busy these days so can't update answer right now